# Error occures while submiting sitecore forms

Tags: sitecore-forms

We have such console errors logged while submitting the Sitecore forms. We are using Sitecore 9.3.

We have used multi-page form and when submitting the form it submits the data but in the developer tool it shows such an error with thank you page.

```
VM2954:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Constructor')
    at <anonymous>:1:19
    at b (jquery.min.js:2:839)
    at Function.globalEval (jquery.min.js:2:2878)
    at Object.dataFilter (jquery.min.js:2:80619)
    at jquery.min.js:2:79084
    at l (jquery.min.js:2:79486)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:2:82254)
    at Object.send (jquery.min.js:2:82613)
    at Function.ajax (jquery.min.js:2:78223)
    at Function.<anonymous> (jquery-migrate.js:378:22)
    
VM2567:3 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'parse')
    at HTMLFormElement.eval (eval at a (jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js:16:157), <anonymous>:3:25)
    at Object.success (jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js:16:1361)
    at c (VM2387 jquery.min.js:2:28294)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (VM2387 jquery.min.js:2:29039)
    at l (VM2387 jquery.min.js:2:79800)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (VM2387 jquery.min.js:2:82254)
eval @ VM2567:3
success @ jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js:16
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen such issues with the Sitecore form. If you are using a `bundling/minification` try with unbundled js once to get more information for syntax error if this occurs due to any custom js file.
Also if required js are not loading in a required order then possibly such error occurs.

Try out the below fixes

1. Make sure `jquery.min.js` file load only once on the page.
2. Check the order of the experience forms scripts.

   [image]

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks @Sumit, Your input works for us, jquery.min was loading multiple times.